# How to store multidimensional array data and update it by key

Tags: laravel-5, multidimensional-array, insert-update

1. I am developing a store and update function for multidimensional array.
2. There is a hidden id coming from a form which needs to be unique as the forms are cloned.
   How can i store that data from the form with a hidden value ?
3. I have already tried a for loop and a for-each loop but I was unable to store the unique hidden value which is coming null from the form
4. All data should be saved with unique hidden data  and updated by these unique key.

Comment: What kind of storage method are you talking about?

Comment: Have you verified that the hidden value is correctly set in the form's source code?

Comment: yes i have verified

Comment: when i dd the request i get
array:7 [
  "address_heading" => array:3 [
    0 => "address_heading_1"
    1 => "address_heading_1"
    2 => "address_heading_3"
  ]
  "address_subheading" => array:3 [
    0 => "address_subheading_1"
    1 => "address_subheading_2"
    2 => "address_subheading_3"
  ]
  "address" => array:3 [
    0 => "address_1"
    1 => "address_2"
    2 => "address_3"
  ]

Comment: If you have verified that a unique hidden value is being set within the form for each request but it is null by the time you come to store it you need to trace that error. Step through the code, starting with the raw request data.